# Laravel 5.8: Parameter passed to the event listener is getting null

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8, laravel-events

I have created an Event called `UserWalletNewTransaction.php` and added this to it:

```
public $transaction;

public function __construct($transaction) {
    $this->$transaction = $transaction;
}
```

And also registered it at `EventServiceProivder.php`:

```
use App\Listeners\UserWalletNotification;

protected $listen = [
    UserWalletNewTransaction::class => [
        UserWalletNotification::class,
    ],
```

Now in order to fire this event at the Controller, I coded this:

```
$newTransaction = UserWalletTransaction::create(['user_id' => $user_id, 'wallet_id' => $wallet_id, 'creator_id' => $creator_id, 'amount' => $amount_add_value, 'description' => $trans_desc]);

event(new UserWalletNewTransaction($newTransaction));
```

Then at the Listener, `UserWalletNotification.php`, I tried:

```
public function handle(UserWalletNewTransaction $event) {
    dd($event->transaction);
}
```

But it returns *`null`* somehow.

However if I `dd($event)` instead, I get this:

[image]

So what is going wrong here? I can properly insert new record at `user_wallet_transactions` and the variable `$newTransaction` should contain the `transaction` information but it's not.

Here is also the Model `UserWalletTransaction.php`:

```
protected $fillable = ['user_id','wallet_id','amount','description','creator_id'];
protected $table = 'user_wallet_transactions';
```

I would really appreciate any idea or suggestion from you guys about this...

Thanks in advance.

---

**UPDATE #1**:

If I do `dd($newTransaction)` at the Controller before `event()`, I get this:

[image]

---

**UPDATE #2**:

Here is the full code of event, `UserWalletNewTransaction.php`:

```
class UserWalletNewTransaction
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public $transaction;

    public function __construct($transaction)
    {
        $this->$transaction = $transaction;
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATE #3:**

Here is the full result of `dd($event)` at the Listener:

```
App\Events\UserWalletNewTransaction {#2533 ▼
  +newTransaction: null
  +socket: null
  +"{"user_id":"373","wallet_id":"2","creator_id":2,"amount":"-60","description":null,"updated_at":"2021-07-18 13:33:59","created_at":"2021-07-18 13:33:59","id":61}": App\UserWalletTransaction {#2535 ▼
    #fillable: array:5 [▼
      0 => "user_id"
      1 => "wallet_id"
      2 => "amount"
      3 => "description"
      4 => "creator_id"
    ]
    #table: "user_wallet_transactions"
    #connection: "mysql"
    #primaryKey: "id"
    #keyType: "int"
    +incrementing: true
    #with: []
    #withCount: []
    #perPage: 15
    +exists: true
    +wasRecentlyCreated: true
    #attributes: array:8 [▼
      "user_id" => "373"
      "wallet_id" => "2"
      "creator_id" => 2
      "amount" => "-60"
      "description" => null
      "updated_at" => "2021-07-18 13:33:59"
      "created_at" => "2021-07-18 13:33:59"
      "id" => 61
    ]
    #original: array:8 [▼
      "user_id" => "373"
      "wallet_id" => "2"
      "creator_id" => 2
      "amount" => "-60"
      "description" => null
      "updated_at" => "2021-07-18 13:33:59"
      "created_at" => "2021-07-18 13:33:59"
      "id" => 61
    ]
    #changes: []
    #casts: []
    #dates: []
    #dateFormat: null
    #appends: []
    #dispatchesEvents: []
    #observables: []
    #relations: []
    #touches: []
    +timestamps: true
    #hidden: []
    #visible: []
    #guarded: array:1 [▼
      0 => "*"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: What happens if you `dd($newTransaction)` before doing `event` ?

Comment: @matiaslauriti I just added an **UPDATE #1**.

Comment: so the record gets created. I am so confused...

Comment: @matiaslauriti Yeah the record can be created, there must be something within the event which is `UserWalletNewTransaction.php`. I put the whole code of it as **UPDATE #2**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just figured out the problem... You are doing `$this->$transaction` when it should be `$this->transaction`.

Comment: Thank you! that was a silly mistake haha

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem, in case it is the case: remove the underscores in the properties of the event. ($_order has to be $order)